# Override Spartacus BadRequestHandler interceptor

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In a Spartacus 4.2 B2B Storefront Login process, I need to override the function handleBadPassword at the BadRequestHandler interceptor. The reason to that is that i want to intercept an specific custom error that the BE responds when a BUnit is blocked, and replace the default GlobalMessage           key from 'httpHandlers.badRequestPleaseLoginAgain', to a custom one 'disabled.login'.

Ive extended the BadRequestHandler class to a CustomBadRequestHandler, I have overridden the required method and added the Provider of the new interceptor to the respective module where I am using it, but it has no effect and I wonder if it is possible to do what I am trying to do and how?

Comment: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/http-error-handling/
If you have done everything as described here, the only thing I would suspect is an incorrect provider placement